# The Most Efficient CSS Selector: Header Tag, Class or ID?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

As we have new elements in HTML5 (HEADER,FOOTER,SECTION...), how should we structure our CSS selectors to improve performance?

```css
header {}
header nav {}
header nav ul li{}
```

**OR**

```css
#header {}
#header .nav{}
#header .nav .menu{}
```

Or in some other, more efficient way?

Comment: css means cascade style sheet, wich means the max you can reuse for other tags the best, with this in mind, it depends of your website/application...

Comment: lets suppose i will use header only once in the page then it make no difference if i use `header` or `#header` right?

Comment: down voters plz comment?

Comment: the browser is gonna find the classes faster, but the "faster" here in ur case is prolly unnoticeable

Comment: I definitely disagree this question is being closed. How is it not constructive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by 'efficiency' you mean how it affects the load time of the page, then you should stick to classes and IDs over tag names. Google has a [best practices page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#UseEfficientCSSSelectors) for writing speedy CSS that you might find interesting. The gist of their advice is to reduce how many elements the browser has to sort through.

The most pertinent point on the page is, again, to *"prefer class and ID selectors over tag selectors."* As we'll see in a minute, this really only improves efficiency when those class and ID selectors reduce the number of matched elements.

Before I get to that, though, let's take the sum of the advice from that page to its logical conclusion. We should find that the most efficient way to write CSS is by applying an ID to everything on your page and only use ID selectors. But should you do this? Probably not.

The reason why is that there are other factors to consider when writing CSS. Here are a few:

1. It is likely that there are other things on your page that take much longer than the processing of CSS, no matter how inefficient your selector is. If you're spending time on optimization, it might be better spent elsewhere.
2. You want to keep your webpage `semantic`, which definitely does not mean giving everything on your page an ID.
3. It would be a pain to maintain such a structure
4. It would be aesthetically unpleasing HTML

What I draw from all of this is to follow the best practices for efficiency so long as you don't sacrifice too many of the above points, especially the first and second.

For your specific examples, the simplest answer is that the bottom selectors will be more efficient if they reduce the number of matched items.

Going through them one-by-one:

`header` vs. `#header`

The ID will always be more efficient if there are multiple header elements on your page. If there is just one header, then they should be equally speedy.

`header nav` vs. `#header .nav`

The Google best practices page tells us that the descendant selectors are the most inefficient selectors in CSS.

This is because CSS reads right to left. Once it finds the right-most descendant, it needs to work its way back through the DOM tree to determine if any of its parents match. And it has to do this for every match.

It happens that selector stops interpreting when it fails to match. So if it's looking for a nav and runs across a ul, it won't go up the DOM tree looking for a header parent of that ul. This shouldn't surprise us too much, but I just thought I'd mention it for completeness.

These points together lead us to the conclusion that you want the right-most piece of a selector to be as specific as possible when using descendant selectors. This maximizes the number of elements that don't match, therefore minimizing the number of slow DOM tree searches.

So back to the two selectors in your example: if you have multiple headers with multiple navs in them, but only a handful of them have the class `.nav`, then the right will be more efficient.
If you have just one header with an ID of header and one nav with an ID of nav, then they will be equally speedy.

`header nav ul li` vs. `#header .nav .menu`

The same rules from before apply to this case. In this case, however, the difference in speediness is amplified by the fact that there are two descendant selectors here, rather than just one.

If your page has multiple unordered lists, then you'll probably want to go with the second of those two selectors to prevent every `li` on your page from matching this (more) complicated selector.

Comment: i liked ur answers but this line, " (when a class is only used for one tag, which is a good design practice anyway)" bite me, cuz it goes agains css proposal.

Comment: so you mean its better to give `<header id="header" >` asd apply css to the #header

Comment: @Ark, the way that I'm interpreting that line is the opposite of how you are. I'm reading it as "Not only is it bad to use something like `.class #id`, but you should avoid using classes for one thing anyway" and it is that second clause that it is referring to as a good design practice. Not that using a class for one instance is a good design practice.

Comment: @Champ, I elaborated on my answer a bit including your specific examples. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how they are going to be used. If they only need to be styled once then use header {} otherwise add classes and/or IDs.

Comment: ur starting from the point that he is not gonna have more than a single li or ul in the nav, thats not trully right