# Trying to add sub-menu to css

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I'm trying to add a sub-menu to the css at http://jsfiddle.net/hozey/9dGuc/, but can't seem to get the hang of it.  Could someone please help this newbie? Here's the html. I want to make a sub-menu for Horses 1, 2 and 3.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<!--begin to insert contents-->
<li class="item-first"><a href="http://www.lawsart.com" target="_top">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="current">Portfolio &#9660;</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horses1.html" target="_top">Horses 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horses2.html" target="_top">Horses 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horses3.html" target="_top">Horses 3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Dogs.html" target="_top">Dogs</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/People.html" target="_top">People</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Stills.html" target="_top">Stills</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Order.html" target="_top">Order</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Contact.html" target="_top">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- end menu -->

</div>
```

Here's the css I've got so far:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  border: px solid black;
  margin: 1em auto;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  width: 760px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:150px;
}

.menu {font-family: arial, sans-serif;width:760px;position:relative;font-size:0.7em; margin:0px auto;}

.menu ul li a {display:block; 
               text-decoration:none; 
               width:97px; 
               height:25px; 
               text-align:center; 
               color:white; 
               padding-left:1x; 
               border:px solid; 
               border-width:0 0px 0px 0; 
               background:; 
               line-height:25px; 
               font-size:1.0em;}

.menu ul {padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type: none; }

.menu ul li {float:left;position:relative;}

.menu ul li ul {visibility:hidden;position:absolute;}

.menu ul li:hover a, .menu ul li a:hover {color:white;background:#3BA110;}

.menu ul li:hover ul, .menu ul li a:hover ul {visibility:visible;left:0;}

.menu ul li:hover ul li a, .menu ul li a:hover ul li a {display:block; 
                                                        background:#444444; 
                                                        color:white; 
                                                        width:97px; 
                                                        padding-left:1px;
                                                        border-right:none;}

.menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover, .menu ul li a:hover ul li a:hover {background:#3BA110;color:white;}
```

Comment: If you try to implement a CSS sub-menu without the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators), you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: How do you want the submenu to appear? Off to the right of the parent element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This will get you started](http://jsfiddle.net/QR9S5/), though it's far from perfect. As Zeta pointed out, [without the child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators), making a deeply nested menu is not only difficult, but it also results in bad code.

What you need to do is make sure you know *exactly* what each of your selectors is targeting. You want your second and third tier `li`s to behave differently, so you need to be certain that your selector for the second isn't also effecting the third.

Literally all that I did to solve your problem was apply the child combinator all over the place on the code you already had, as I knew you were writing code for first and second tier menu items. After that, I tacked on a simple selector to target third tier items and had a working menu.

Were I you, I'd go back through your code and make sure you know exactly what your selectors are targeting, then rewrite your CSS. It's not too hard to do, and it can result in surprisingly little code for very complex nested menus.

## html (for just a third tier menu item)

```
...
<!-- the rest of the menu -->
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horses1.html" target="_top">Horses 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Submenu1</li>
      <li>Submenu2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<!-- the rest of the menu -->
...
```

## css (for just the third tier)

```
.menu ul ul ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 97px; }
.menu ul ul li:hover ul { visibility: visible; background-color: #eee; }
```

And just for a few examples of how to select different tier menus and items:

### css (to target the 'header items')

```
.menu > ul > li { }
```

### css (to target the first dropdown)

```
.menu > ul > li > ul { }
```

### css (to target the first dropdown items)

```
.menu > ul > li > ul > li { }
.menu ul ul > li { } /* This will also target submenu items */
.menu > ul > ul > li { }
```

### css (to target the submenu to a dropdown item)

```
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul { }
.menu ul ul ul { }
```

### css (to target the submenu item of a dropdown item)

```
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li { }
.menu ul ul ul li { }
```

What we can gather from the above code is that you don't want to stop doing using the child combinator until you're at the last tier of your menu. In general, `menu ul[n] li`, where I'm using pseudocode to represent *n* number of `ul`s, will target any *li* deeper than *n* depth in your menu. So in your case, it's fine to use `.menu ul ul ul li` as the third tier is the last one. But you wouldn't want to use `.menu ul ul li` to write style that's meant just for the first dropdown, as that selector also targets the third, fourth, and so on depth as well.

Just for completeness, the bare minimum to get a working deeply nested menu is done by thinking like this:

You want anything after the first *ul* to start off as hidden. So you can do:

```
.menu ul ul { visibility: hidden; }
```

This hides any *ul* that is nested within another *ul*. So it hits all of our submenus. And it only applies to lists within our menu.

Then you want each submenu to be visible when you're hovering over its parent's link. We can handle all of our submenus with a single selector, I think:

```
.menu li:hover > ul { visibility: visible; }
```

That should be general enough to apply to every level of a menu. Reading right to left, we make the *ul* visible when we're hovering over an *li* that is its direct parent. And, like usual, this only applies to an *li* that is within our menu.

Of course, you could use *a*, too, if you wanted.

CSS Menus are a great time to think and learn about [CSS efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156362/the-most-efficient-css-selector-header-tag-class-or-id/14156622#14156622). Once you have a working menu, see if you can optimize it! The tags I posted here might not be the quickest; I just thought of them off the top of my head. I'll leave it to you to find the best selectors to use.

And that's really the basics of complex nested CSS menus. Hope it helps.